# Non documented jsonb_to_tsvector function

Tags: postgresql

I am using PstgreSQL v12, and there is a native function `\df jsonb_to_tsvector`... But it is not described at [pg guide functions-json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) neither other page. It is a interesting function, can I use it, is reliable?  Or it is a kind of *"lost in namespace" bug*?

Important: even if google found it, **I see citation absence (or absence  of "also see" section) as a PG Guide bug**.  It is a `jsonb_*` native function: all must be cited at pg guide functions-json.

---

## NOTES

At [this old page of 2018](https://www.depesz.com/2018/04/23/waiting-for-postgresql-11-add-jsonb_to_tsvector-function/) we can found something as:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (id int, payload jsonb);
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
  (1,'{"glossary":{"title":"example glossary","GlossDiv":{"title":"S","GlossList":{"GlossEntry":{"ID":"SGML","Abbrev":"ISO 8879:1986","SortAs":"SGML","Acronym":"SGML","GlossDef":{"para":"A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.","GlossSeeAlso":["GML","XML"]},"GlossSee":"markup","GlossTerm":"Standard Generalized Markup Language"}}}}}'::jsonb)
 ,(2,'{"menu":{"id":"file","popup":{"menuitem":[{"value":"New","onclick":"CreateNewDoc()"},{"value":"Open","onclick":"OpenDoc()"},{"value":"Close","onclick":"CloseDoc()"}]},"value":"File"}}'::jsonb)
 ,(3,'{"x":[1,2,3]}'::jsonb)
;
-- it is running and results are fine!
SELECT id, jsonb_to_tsvector('english', payload, '["all"]') FROM test;
SELECT id, jsonb_to_tsvector('english', payload, '["numeric","key"]') FROM test;
```

... and that it is "2 years lost".

---

(edited after answered)

#### Voting the IDEAL GUIDE

At answer comments @a_horse_with_no_name explain my position, *"... with your logic, `array_to_tsvector` would need to be listed with the array functions..."*,
and that his position is the **opposit**.

The Stackoverflow community **is democratic**, we can use an efficient voting mechanism. I am creating a Wiki answer to you vote below as an alternative answer... Let's do an experiment. Each answer is an **postion alternative**:

- [vote this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63245451/287948) for *"**no** See also section"* and no citations. You agree that Guide is good as it is, and a hub page not need to cite other functions.
- [vote this other answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63249966/287948) for *"**See also** section"* or completeness of citations. You agree that the Guide is not good, and a hub page need to cite other functions.

#### Time to vote at `postgresql.org/docs`?

I never understood why **"our"** PostgreSQL guide at [`postgresql.org/docs`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/) does not offer *"See also" sections*.

Almost all Wikipedia articles have a *"See also" section*, and almost all popular programming languages:
PHP [example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php#refsect1-function.str-replace-seealso), PostGIS [example](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html), etc. or "see also" box like [Python guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.vformat).

In a good programming language it is not difficult to classify and define groups of native functions, on the basis of shared characteristics.
PostgreSQL have a [big community](https://www.postgresql.org/community/), so it is *easy also to check consensus* about defining groups of similar native functions... And sometimes is more easy: all functions with the prefix `array_` are in the set of "all native array functions", all functions with the prefix `jsonb_` are in the set of "all native JSONb functions".

It is also a  kind of "completeness  princicle for Guides": a Guide's page that explain "all functions of group G" need to explain, or at least to cite, all functions of the G group. The page "JSON functions" is for all native JSON functions, the page "ARRAY functions"   is for all native JSON functions.

PS: about "native function" definition in this context, [extensions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/external-extensions.html) are excluded from it. For example jsonb functions and array functions of extensions, like [hstore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html) are not native.

Problem: is there, at `postgresql.org/docs`, a democratic mechanism to vote, like here?

Comment: This is no longer a question suited for stackoverflow. Whether or not the current document structure is good is highly subjective and thus "opinion based" and should be closed. If you want to leave feedback on the documentation you can do that [here](https://www.postgresql.org/account/comments/new/12/functions-json.html/) or on the [mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-docs/) - which is probably as close as it gets regarding a "voting" community.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks... Makes sense, I am also  testing (without expectation) the [submit correction mechanism](https://www.postgresql.org/account/comments/new/12/functions-textsearch.html/)... No expectation because is a project decision, and they will say that there are "no corrections" to be made.  About here, the best is?  to DELETE, to WAIT or  to EDIT?

Answer (score 3):

The function is documented in the [text search functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html)

> reduce each value in the document, specified by filter to a tsvector, and then concatenate those in document order to produce a single tsvector.

Comment: Thanks  (!)...  Yes, the direct google found it. But the real problem here is the "guide bug".  It is the best page to show function in its context, but any good guide have some citation or "see also" section, in the other "good candidate places". **It is a `jsonb_*` native function**.

Comment: I disagree. It's a text search function because it only makes sense to use it in the context of a text search. Btw: I found it by going straight to the chapter about text search functions as all functions involving `tsvector` are listed there. With your logic, `array_to_tsvector` would need to be listed with the array functions. Or `sum()` needs to be listed with the numeric functions.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes, we do not agree, our opinions are opposite... Or maybe not so much, I re-edited the question trying to express better the point. There are no "correct position", but an interface bug is a bug when the user community show its position. I am proposing an experiment to get this "community position".

Answer (score -1):

This answer is a Wiki (your vote goes to nobody) and is not a real answer, it is a kind of voting experient... I is a "place to vote" an alternative position.  The two alternatives are:

- here
- and [the
  a_horse_with_no_name answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63245451/287948).

### Position here: the Guide needs a "see also" section or similar thing

*"**See also** section"* or function name citations, for completeness in a "all native functions of group" page. Example: the page Guide of [all native ARRAY functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html), the page of all [all native JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), etc.

Vote here if you agree that the Guide is not good, and a hub page need to cite other functions.